# Python / Selenium : Switch to an alert and verify the text within

Tags: python, selenium

My issue: Being able to detect an alert box has been opened, verify the text inside the alert, confirm the text and then close the alert. Then, go back and correct the invalid email.

My test is one for registering a user. I need to validate when someone might input incorrect data or mismatched data. In this case, I am entering an email and verifying the email first entered. Should they have a mismatch, a popup will appear alerting the user to check the email addresses they have entered and that they match. So far all I can get is an error.

Error:

> E       UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Message: u'Modal dialog
>   present' ; Stacktrace: Method nsCommandProcessor.prototype.execute
>   threw an error in file:///var/folders/1j/x3cxkrqn3sscdyq0t36169hr0000gn/T/tmpTCqMgm/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js

I thought my code would handle this, but nope. If someone could point out my, obvious to you, mistake I would be grateful.

My entire test code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import unittest, time, re

class ChallengeTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        self.base_url = "https://www.testpage.com"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True

# SIGN UP NEW USER

    def test_00_sign_up(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.base_url + "/")
        driver.find_element_by_id("remail").send_keys("foobar@me.com")
        driver.find_element_by_id("remail_confirm").send_keys("bar@me.com")
        driver.find_element_by_id("next").click()
        alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
        alert = self.assertTrue(self.is_text_present("The email addresses you entered"))
        driver.find_element_by_id("remail_confirm").send_keys("foobar@me.com")
        driver.find_element_by_id("registration_button").click()

# NON TESTS

    def is_element_present(self, how, what):
        try:
            self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what) # to find page elements
        except NoSuchElementException, e: return False
        return True     

    def is_text_present(self, text):
        try:
            body = self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body") # find body tag element
        except NoSuchElementException, e: return False
        return text in body.text # check if the text is in body's text

    def is_alert_present(self):
        try:
            self.driver.switch_to_alert()
        except NoAlertPresentException, e: 
            return False

    def close_alert_and_get_its_text(self):
        try:
            alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
            alert_text = alert.text
            if self.accept_next_alert:
                alert.accept()
            else:
                alert.dismiss()
            return alert_text
        finally: self.accept_next_alert = True        
        return True

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)
```

Comment: Have you tried commenting out the implicit wait and running your test that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try waiting for the alert to appear, before directly switching to it.

If that does not work, I have a feeling that the popup actually is a weblement and not a JS alert. if that is the case try looking for a selector using the browser developer tools and directly interact with it.

Comment: You are correct, it is a webelement. However, I can not get the attribute of the element to interact with it. Once I have that, I can interact with it eg: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html Under the 6.3 If you can tell me how to get the ID/Name of the webelement, that would be outstanding.

Comment: When the alert is generated, try inspecting the element using Firebug or Chrome Developer tools. That should be a good way to start. Once you find the element, you would not need the interaction methods listed under the 6.3 module.

Comment: I tried using Firebug and Charles Proxy. I (Firebug) can not see it. I am sure this is due to my lack of knowing where to look though, for Charles.

Comment: Thank you very much Dave! You saved my afternoon! :)
PS: have you tried to use get_alert()? It worked for me!

Answer (score 5):

On newer version of Python(3.4)

```
def is_alert_present(self):
    try:
        self.driver.switch_to_alert()
    except NoAlertPresentException: 
        return False
```

Comment: Please do elaborate your answer.

Comment: When I try to paste the code on the newer version of Python, it gave me an error. Then I tried this method it worked properly.